# How to use useEffect on button Click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, fetch, use-effect

I've to call `useEffect` **/** `Fetch the data` only when user `click on Search Button` otherwise not fetch the data..

**Code:**

```
const App = () => {

const[datas,setDatas] = useState([]) 

const [space,setSpace] = useState(null)
const [print, setPrint] = useState(false)


function getData(val){
 // console.log(val.target.value)
  setSpace(val.target.value);
  setPrint(false)
}

// console.log(space)  

  useEffect(() => {
    const fecthPosts = async () => {
      let initial_url = `http://localhost:4000/search` 
      let url = initial_url + "?text=" + space  
       
       const res = await fetch(url);
       const {result} = await res.json();

     setDatas(result);
    fecthPosts();     //I've to call this fetchPosts() when Btn is CLicked
  },[space]);

return(
 <div className="App">
     {                  //Displaying on search
        print?
         <>
        <h2>{space}</h2>  
        <div> 
       {datas.map((field) => 
       <p>{field.title}</p> 
       <p>{field.author}</p> 
       )}
        </div>
        </>
        :null
      }
   <input type="text" onChange={getData} />
   <button onClick={() => { setSpace(true); fetchPosts() }}>search</button>
 </div>
  )
 }
};

export default App;
```

It's not working **Error:**

```
 fetchPosts() is not defined...
```

---

**I've also tried like this:**

```
function trigger(){
  useEffect(() => {
    const fecthPosts = async () => {
      let initial_url = `http://localhost:4000/search` 
      let url = initial_url + "?text=" + space  
       
       const res = await fetch(url);
       const {result} = await res.json();

     setDatas(result);
    fecthPosts();     //I've to call this fetchPosts() when Btn is CLicked
  },[space]);
}

<button onClick={() => { setSpace(true); trigger() }}>search</button>
```

It's not working **Error:**

```
 React Hook useEffect has unnecessary dependencies:'space'
```

**/PLZZ help to out...**

Comment: You should declare your `fetchPosts` function outside the `useEffect` and bind it directly to `button` click. No need to use `useEffect` and the extra state `space`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your fetchPosts outside of the `useEffect`.
Then, you can use a new state `search` to track any click on the button.

```
const App = () => {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  const [space, setSpace] = useState(null);
  const [print, setPrint] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(false);

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    let initial_url = `http://localhost:4000/search`;
    let url = initial_url + "?text=" + space;

    const res = await fetch(url);
    const { result } = await res.json();
    setDatas(result);
  };

  function getData(val) {
    setSpace(val.target.value);
    setPrint(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts(); // fecthPosts is called each time space changed
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        //Displaying on search
        print ? (
          <>
            <h2>{space}</h2>
            <div>
              {datas.map((field) => (
                <>
                  <p>{field.title}</p>
                  <p>{field.author}</p>
                </>
              ))}
            </div>
          </>
        ) : null
      }
      <input type="text" onChange={getData} />
      <button onClick={() => setSearch(!search)}>search</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

make a separate function for api call and in your UseEffect function just call that function and on Button click function call the Api Function and it fetch data automatically

Answer (score 1):

## Use useCallback not useEffect

useCallback is similar to useEffect but is for when a function needs a callback, like what you're doing here onClick. useEffect is used in response to some prop changing not an action taken by a user.

Answer (score 0):

I initialized `shouldFetchData = false`. Once the button is clicked, I changed it's value; `shouldFetchData = true`. Inside useEffect I called `fetchPosts()` only when `shouldFetchData` is `true`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {

    const [datas, setDatas] = useState([])
    const [shouldFetchData, setShouldFetchData] = useState(false);
    const [space, setSpace] = useState(null)
    const [print, setPrint] = useState(false)


    function getData(val) {
        // console.log(val.target.value)
        setSpace(val.target.value);
        setPrint(false)
    }

    // console.log(space)  

    const fecthPosts = async () => {
        let initial_url = `http://localhost:4000/search`
        let url = initial_url + "?text=" + space

        const res = await fetch(url);
        const { result } = await res.json();

        setDatas(result);
        fecthPosts();     //I've to call this fetchPosts() when Btn is CLicked
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(shouldFetchData) {
            fecthPosts();
        }
    }, [space]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {
                print ?
                    <>
                        <h2>{space}</h2>
                        <div>
                            {datas.map((field) =>
                                <>
                                    <p>{field.title}</p>
                                    <p>{field.author}</p>
                                </>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </>
                    : null
            }
            <input type="text" onChange={getData} />
            <button onClick={() => {
                setSpace(true);
                setShouldFetchData(true);
            }}>search</button>
        </div>
    )
};

export default App;
```

I found a few syntax errors in your code, so I hope I did what you intended.
If This is not the proper way to do this or if there exists a better way, please let me know. I'd be happy to learn.